# What is the partition function to partition a number into "same sub-parts"?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

All:

What is the partition function to partition a number into "same sub-parts" ?

For "same sub-parts", we mean that a partition function which gives a partition such as:

6 = 2 + 2 + 2 =3 + 3 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

I know it is not difficult to the number of partition directly for this question, but I still want to get a partition function for this.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You get one such partition for each divisor of $n$: if $d$ is a divisor of $n$, you can partition $n$ into $\frac{n}d$ summands $d$. Moreover, every partition of $n$ into equal parts is of this form The number of such partitions is therefore the number of divisors of $n$; this is sometimes denoted by $\tau(n)$, but I think that $\sigma_0(n)$ may be more common, as in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). This function has the following properties:

- $\sigma_0(p)=2$ for primes $p$;
- $\sigma_0(p^k)=k+1$ for primes $p$;
- if $n$ has the prime factorization $n=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\ldots p_m^{r_m}$, then $\sigma_0(n)=\prod_{k=1}^m(r_k+1)$.

The third point follows from the fact that $\sigma_0$ is a multiplicative function: $\sigma_0(mn)=\sigma_0(m)\sigma_0(n)$ if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

The values of $\sigma_0(n)$ form the sequence [OEIS A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005), and you can find much information at that link. There is no nice closed form, but there are some interesting formulas nonetheless, e.g.,

$$\sigma_0(n)=n-\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left\lceil\frac{n}k\right\rceil-\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor\right)\;.$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  Is there a generating function whose coefficient will product the number of partitions to partition a number into "equal sub-parts" ?  I know there are other ways to get this partition number, but I am particularly interested to get this number through a generating function.

Comment: The OEIS link offers several generating functions, though all appear to be infinite series of functions, e.g., $$\sum_{k>0}\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}\;,$$ a [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series), so I don’t know how useful you’ll find them.